# How to use a big bunch of photos in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating an iOS app where I need to use many photos(in big resolution). There're almost 400 photos. I want to use them to show in UIImageView on the different pages.
But it's a big bunch of data. So I'm afraid about efficient(not so much) and size of the app itself. What's the best way to use these photos in my iOS app? Does it make sense to create New Image Set and create 1x,2x and 3x photos for each photo or do I have to use other features I don't now about?

UPD1:
The app is about sights. From the tableview user can chose any sight and will be shown screen with 1-3 photos( in CollectionView if there's more than 1 photo) and some text. All data(except photos) I'm getting from sqlite db using CoreData.

The photos are shown on the screen have width equal to screen width (the height 25:38 from width). Width is bigger:)

1. I want to use big resolution photos because I want show full-size
   photos by tap.
2. Each photo can be 2000px or more on the biggest
   side.
3. The app is an offline app so I want to store photos in the
   app. I now just about image assets. But are there other ways to
   store photos?

I have an idea to store them in high-resolution and resize to any device(3x, 2x, 1x) to display on the screen. And load high-resolution version of a photo just when user taps on it to show the photo on the full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load all the photos from the app - this is btw. not possible because of memory issues during loading images.

You should at the beginning think about presenting photos and photos itself.

- Do you really need to show photos in big resolution?
- What big resolution means? Is that 1024x1024 or native resolution or what?
- From where these photos are loaded? App includes it or you'll load them from system library? I see you're writing about image assets, probably you want to keep them in the app.
- Do you need to show this images in constant almost 0 time? Maybe keeping it on the backend and fetching and cache when necessary will be better approach. With this you can decrease size of the app.
- You can keep in assets only the biggest one - the @3x and resize it on devices that need this in runtime before displaying it.

To keep photos in device's memory you can use `NSCache` - [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library//mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html) and let system managing the photos. You'll load this and cache in the instance of `NSCache` and every time you want to access it and get photo you have to check if there is photo or nil and if nil you have to re-load it again from the disk. This will somehow keep your device to not get memory warnings and will automatically managing photos.

- Another important thing to think is to how you plan to show the photos. Is is possible to show only 1 at a time or there is more to show? Do you want to present thumbnails of them and after user select some photo show it in the big resolution? Using thumbnails will have less memory footprint.

**Update 1**:

> UPD1: The app is about sights. From the tableview user can chose any places and will be shown screen with 1-3 photos( in CollectionView if there's more than 1 photo) and some text. All data(except photos) I'm getting from sqlite db using CoreData.
>
> The app is an offline app so I want to store photos in the app. I now just about image assets. But are there other ways to store photos?

You don't need assets catalog for this. Just keep it in some directory in the project and load them from /Documents directory when necessary. IMO this will be the best possible approach to store and use locally. Keeping them in the assets will cause that there will be @1x and @2x empty in xcassets file. And keeping them directly in project will be easier to maintain I think.

> I want to use big resolution photos because I want show full-size photos by tap.
>   Each photo can be 2000px or more on the biggest side.
>
> I have an idea to store them in high-resolution and resize to any device(3x, 2x, 1x) to display on the screen. And load high-resolution when user taps on the photo to show photo on the full screen.

Keeping such big photos in the app is poor idea, the app will be big. Even if one photo will be 1mb size which I think is not possible and there are 400 photos the app will be fat.

You should consider keeping them online, really.

You also know all the images in the app so you can create thumbnails in real time and cache them in /Cache directory for later use. The same with big photos for specified device screen resolution. Before displaying resize it and save in /Cache directory for future next time use.

Comment: I've updated me question because update was to big for the comments. I want to know what's the best way to store so many photos in the app and how to efficiently control them to show. Than you

Comment: "Just keep it in some directory in the project and load them from /Documents directory when necessary." Do I understand you right? To store photos there I have to save them to  `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]; ` ?

Comment: In the second part of your answer you mean to download big photo from online, resize it and save in /Cache resized copies? And load full-size photos to show them on the full-screen when necessary?

Comment: If you add files to the project, the files will be in the bundle so you can read them from `NSDocumentsDirectory`. You don't need to save them there - They are there waiting to be used

Comment: In the second answer I meant that no matter if you download file from server or read from /Documents you have to process it to show to the user in native screen resolution. So you should process file and save it in /Cache directory `NSCachesDirectory`. This directory is managed by the system and data can be removed at any time. Probably only when user launch app. So you have to check if file exist in cache, if yes load them and  you can show it without processing before file is ready to use. If there is no file then load from /Documents, process and save again to /Cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83687/discussion-between-denfav-and-tomasz-szulc).